# grid.draw() gives "object 'd' not found" error with gridExtra loaded

Tags: r, gridextra, r-grid

I generated a 20Cx10R table with tableGrob and found it very slow. I thus tried to figure out why. Baptiste himself mentioned the reason in [Has anyone else noticed that tableGrob is slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514217/has-anyone-else-noticed-that-tablegrob-is-slow).

I tried his example in: http://rpubs.com/baptiste/ftableGrob. Initial run was good, i.e. the table in his example generated very quickly.

But when I tried to load gridExtra to add a plot from ggplot, **`grid.draw(g)` generated this error: `Error in as.matrix(d) : object 'd' not found`**

My code is here (modified slightly from baptiste's original):

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)  # NOTE: Loading gridExtra clashes w grid.draw(g) later

aa <- head(iris, 10)
padding = unit(4, "mm")

nc <- ncol(aa)
nr <- nrow(aa)

extended_matrix <- cbind(c("", rownames(aa)), rbind(colnames(aa), as.matrix(aa)))
w <- apply(extended_matrix, 2, strwidth, "inch")
h <- apply(extended_matrix, 2, strheight, "inch")

widths <- apply(w, 2, max)
heights <- apply(h, 1, max)

padding <- convertUnit(padding, unitTo = "in", valueOnly = TRUE)

x <- cumsum(widths + padding) - 0.5 * padding
y <- cumsum(heights + padding) - padding

rg <- rectGrob( x = unit(x - widths/2, "in"), y = unit(1, "npc") - 
                 unit(rep(y, each = nc + 1), "in"), 
               width = unit(widths + padding, "in"), 
               height = unit(heights + padding, "in") )
tg <- textGrob( c(t(extended_matrix)), x = unit(x - widths/2, "in"), 
               y = unit(1, "npc") - unit(rep(y, each = nc + 1), "in"), 
               just = "center" )

g <- gTree( children = gList(rg, tg), x = x, y = y, widths = widths, 
           heights = heights, cl = "table", 
            gp=gpar(fill = rep(c("grey90", "grey95"), each = 2)))

l <- linesGrob()
grid.draw(l)  # Added to show that grid.draw works here...

grid.draw(g)  # ... but not here *confused*
invisible(g)

grid.arrange( g, g, ncol=2)  # I eventually hope to use ggplot2 w the tables drawn with grid.draw

## End of code ##
```

I researched on this but did not find similar reports/posts. I suspect it's due to my poor understanding of gridExtra, so I am bringing this up in SO to seek 'enlightenment'. Would appreciate if someone could help!

An aside: as baptiste's original code also uses 'd', after switching his 'd' to 'aa', R still screamed "object 'd' not found!". Imagine my bewilderment!

Finally, wish all in SO a Happy New Year (2014)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load gridExtra, you bring with it a drawDetails method (called by grid.draw) for objects of class "table" that is not compatible with this gTree (it lacks some attributes). To cut the story short, you should simply remove the `cl = "table"` in your gTree, or pick another name.

Comment: @SlowLearner a new class is only useful if you define a method for it, otherwise grid.draw defaults to the parent method for generic gTrees

Comment: baptiste, my use of `foo` to test was purely reflexive - there was no thought involved. Kinda like the rest of my code really.

Comment: Thanks, @baptiste, it works! (well, who else but you would know gridExtra best!  =)  ). But can I trouble you to explain why you added that line in your code? I mean, is there a practical use of defining g as 'table' since we would mostly just call grid.draw(g)?

Comment: @NoviceProg it was there by mistake, I probably thought initially I'd need a custom draw method, and then forgot about it. I've updated the Rpubs accordingly.

Comment: I see. Excellent, another mystery of the universe solved! Thanks again for your help, @baptiste!

Comment: @baptiste, going back to your code, can I trouble you to guide me on how to centre the entire table (along both x-axis and y-axis)? I tried substituting x=unit(x - widths/2, "in") in rectGrob with x=unit(0.5, "npc"), but that totally messes up the table. Adding a 'just="center"' doesn't work either. Hope I'm not troubling you too much...

Comment: you can use `unit(x - widths/2, "in") - unit(0.5*diff(range(x)), "in") + unit(0.5, "npc")` and similarly for y

Comment: @baptiste, it works for centering along x-axis - that's one step forward! But when I implemented for y-axis: `unit(0.5*diff(range(y)), "in") + unit(0.5, "npc") - unit(rep(y, each=nc+1), "in")`, it appears to be slightly lower than centre. It's quite trivial really but I just hope to clarify with you whether I made a mistake somewhere.